# SFDX CLI missing .exe file

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, illuminatedcloud

I will try to configure sfdx for illuminated cloud 2. After instalation of salesforce cli (I tried both x64 and x86) the sfdx.exe file is missing inside the CLI folder so I can't add the path for this file in the illuminated cloud. With windows cmd and visual studio code everything works as it should. Could you help me with that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `sfdx.exe` file anywhere. SFDX runs from `C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\bin\sfdx.cmd` in Windows (by default). This script ultimately calls node.js (also installed during SFDX CLI installation), which runs the client from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\sfdx\client\bin\sfdx.js`. You need to use the `sfdx.cmd` file. I don't have any familiarity with Illuminated Cloud, so you might need to engage their support or help files on calling `.cmd` files.

Comment: sfdcfox please look on that video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86lwNDZaMSo&t=38s When it comes to exe, you're right, but there must be some other way to attach an exe to this plugin

Comment: @Adamo Yes, the "executable" version was based on the Salesforce CLI, DX now is a totally new piece of software. What happens if you try putting in `C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\bin\sfdx.cmd` in the box for the executable?

Comment: Well, let me tell you that I had to write back as "error occur" but I checked again and it worked. Thank you for guiding to resolve this problem. I do not know why it did not work for the first time. Thanks !

Comment: I also get response from support:  A little back Salesforce changed the Windows installer for the Salesforce CLI so that it installs in a different location and calls the main executable "sfdx.cmd" instead of "sfdx.exe". IC has been updated to know about this change and should find the "sfdx.cmd" executable automatically if both IC and the Salesforce CLI are relatively up-to-date.